# Manual iteration through 2D vector of group nodes

Tags: c++

I have stored a directed graph in a 2D vector and I want to iterate through all the possible path from any directed graph going from left to right via groups in a recursive manner. I have given an example below and want to iterate through all the paths from the first group (in this example G1) to any last group (in this example G3). I have been trying a lot but I'm not able to build a recursive to iterate through all the paths with any amount of groups. So I need help with building a **manual iteration system/algorithm of loops without recursion function calls**. For the iteration part, if I can get an algorithm which can print all the possible paths, it will be more than helpful. So, any source, tips and tricks will be useful. Thanks.

`graph:`

[image]

`script.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  
  vector<int> map = {
    { 1, 2 },
    { 3, 4, 5 },
    { 6, 7 }
  };
  
  // Print all paths
  // Note :- every array in the map is a group
  
  return 0;
}
```

`output:`

```
1 -> 3 -> 6
1 -> 3 -> 7
1 -> 4 -> 6
1 -> 4 -> 7
1 -> 5 -> 6
1 -> 5 -> 7
2 -> 3 -> 6
2 -> 3 -> 7
2 -> 4 -> 6
2 -> 4 -> 7
2 -> 5 -> 6
2 -> 5 -> 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Compile using g++ -std=c++11 code.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main() {

    vector<vector<int> > map = {
        { 1, 2 },
        { 3, 4, 5 },
        { 6, 7 }
    };

    vector<int> sizes(map.size());
    vector<int> indexes(map.size());
    int combinations = 1;

    for(int i=0; i<map.size();i++){
        sizes[i]=map[i].size();
    }

    for(int i=0; i<map.size();i++){
        combinations*=map[i].size();
    }


    for(int combination=1; combination <= combinations; combination++){
        int multiple = 1;
        for(int ind=0; ind<indexes.size(); ind++){
            cout << map[ind][indexes[ind]];
            if(ind < indexes.size()-1) 
                cout << " -> "; 
        }
        cout << endl;
        for(int j=map.size()-1;j>=0;j--){
            multiple*=map[j].size();
            
            
            indexes[map.size()-1]=combination % map[map.size()-1].size();
            
            if(combination % multiple == 0 && j>0){
                //cout << "*";
                indexes[j-1] = (indexes[j-1]+1)%map[j-1].size();

            }

        }
    }

  return 0;
}




vector<vector<int> > map = {
    { 1, 2 },
    { 3, 4, 5, 10, 100 },
    { 6, 7, 8 },
    { 6, 7 },
    { 600, 17 }
};

1 -> 3 -> 6 -> 6 -> 600
1 -> 3 -> 6 -> 6 -> 17
1 -> 3 -> 6 -> 7 -> 600
1 -> 3 -> 6 -> 7 -> 17
1 -> 3 -> 7 -> 6 -> 600
1 -> 3 -> 7 -> 6 -> 17
1 -> 3 -> 7 -> 7 -> 600
1 -> 3 -> 7 -> 7 -> 17
1 -> 3 -> 8 -> 6 -> 600
1 -> 3 -> 8 -> 6 -> 17
1 -> 3 -> 8 -> 7 -> 600
1 -> 3 -> 8 -> 7 -> 17
1 -> 4 -> 6 -> 6 -> 600
1 -> 4 -> 6 -> 6 -> 17
1 -> 4 -> 6 -> 7 -> 600
1 -> 4 -> 6 -> 7 -> 17
1 -> 4 -> 7 -> 6 -> 600
1 -> 4 -> 7 -> 6 -> 17
1 -> 4 -> 7 -> 7 -> 600
1 -> 4 -> 7 -> 7 -> 17
1 -> 4 -> 8 -> 6 -> 600
1 -> 4 -> 8 -> 6 -> 17
1 -> 4 -> 8 -> 7 -> 600
1 -> 4 -> 8 -> 7 -> 17
1 -> 5 -> 6 -> 6 -> 600
1 -> 5 -> 6 -> 6 -> 17
1 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 600
1 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 17
1 -> 5 -> 7 -> 6 -> 600
1 -> 5 -> 7 -> 6 -> 17
1 -> 5 -> 7 -> 7 -> 600
1 -> 5 -> 7 -> 7 -> 17
1 -> 5 -> 8 -> 6 -> 600
1 -> 5 -> 8 -> 6 -> 17
1 -> 5 -> 8 -> 7 -> 600
1 -> 5 -> 8 -> 7 -> 17
1 -> 10 -> 6 -> 6 -> 600
1 -> 10 -> 6 -> 6 -> 17
1 -> 10 -> 6 -> 7 -> 600
1 -> 10 -> 6 -> 7 -> 17
1 -> 10 -> 7 -> 6 -> 600
1 -> 10 -> 7 -> 6 -> 17
1 -> 10 -> 7 -> 7 -> 600
1 -> 10 -> 7 -> 7 -> 17
1 -> 10 -> 8 -> 6 -> 600
1 -> 10 -> 8 -> 6 -> 17
1 -> 10 -> 8 -> 7 -> 600
1 -> 10 -> 8 -> 7 -> 17
1 -> 100 -> 6 -> 6 -> 600
1 -> 100 -> 6 -> 6 -> 17
1 -> 100 -> 6 -> 7 -> 600
1 -> 100 -> 6 -> 7 -> 17
1 -> 100 -> 7 -> 6 -> 600
1 -> 100 -> 7 -> 6 -> 17
1 -> 100 -> 7 -> 7 -> 600
1 -> 100 -> 7 -> 7 -> 17
1 -> 100 -> 8 -> 6 -> 600
1 -> 100 -> 8 -> 6 -> 17
1 -> 100 -> 8 -> 7 -> 600
1 -> 100 -> 8 -> 7 -> 17
2 -> 3 -> 6 -> 6 -> 600
2 -> 3 -> 6 -> 6 -> 17
2 -> 3 -> 6 -> 7 -> 600
2 -> 3 -> 6 -> 7 -> 17
2 -> 3 -> 7 -> 6 -> 600
2 -> 3 -> 7 -> 6 -> 17
2 -> 3 -> 7 -> 7 -> 600
2 -> 3 -> 7 -> 7 -> 17
2 -> 3 -> 8 -> 6 -> 600
2 -> 3 -> 8 -> 6 -> 17
2 -> 3 -> 8 -> 7 -> 600
2 -> 3 -> 8 -> 7 -> 17
2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 6 -> 600
2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 6 -> 17
2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 7 -> 600
2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 7 -> 17
2 -> 4 -> 7 -> 6 -> 600
2 -> 4 -> 7 -> 6 -> 17
2 -> 4 -> 7 -> 7 -> 600
2 -> 4 -> 7 -> 7 -> 17
2 -> 4 -> 8 -> 6 -> 600
2 -> 4 -> 8 -> 6 -> 17
2 -> 4 -> 8 -> 7 -> 600
2 -> 4 -> 8 -> 7 -> 17
2 -> 5 -> 6 -> 6 -> 600
2 -> 5 -> 6 -> 6 -> 17
2 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 600
2 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 17
2 -> 5 -> 7 -> 6 -> 600
2 -> 5 -> 7 -> 6 -> 17
2 -> 5 -> 7 -> 7 -> 600
2 -> 5 -> 7 -> 7 -> 17
2 -> 5 -> 8 -> 6 -> 600
2 -> 5 -> 8 -> 6 -> 17
2 -> 5 -> 8 -> 7 -> 600
2 -> 5 -> 8 -> 7 -> 17
2 -> 10 -> 6 -> 6 -> 600
2 -> 10 -> 6 -> 6 -> 17
2 -> 10 -> 6 -> 7 -> 600
2 -> 10 -> 6 -> 7 -> 17
2 -> 10 -> 7 -> 6 -> 600
2 -> 10 -> 7 -> 6 -> 17
2 -> 10 -> 7 -> 7 -> 600
2 -> 10 -> 7 -> 7 -> 17
2 -> 10 -> 8 -> 6 -> 600
2 -> 10 -> 8 -> 6 -> 17
2 -> 10 -> 8 -> 7 -> 600
2 -> 10 -> 8 -> 7 -> 17
2 -> 100 -> 6 -> 6 -> 600
2 -> 100 -> 6 -> 6 -> 17
2 -> 100 -> 6 -> 7 -> 600
2 -> 100 -> 6 -> 7 -> 17
2 -> 100 -> 7 -> 6 -> 600
2 -> 100 -> 7 -> 6 -> 17
2 -> 100 -> 7 -> 7 -> 600
2 -> 100 -> 7 -> 7 -> 17
2 -> 100 -> 8 -> 6 -> 600
2 -> 100 -> 8 -> 6 -> 17
2 -> 100 -> 8 -> 7 -> 600
2 -> 100 -> 8 -> 7 -> 17
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution, but I'm looking for more of a recursion method (using loops only without function calls) rather than this recursive method.

Comment: That would probably have to take `vector<vector<int>>`, right? Because otherwise `group[index].size()` and `group[index][i]` will be compilation errors since `int`s don't have a `size` method and aren't subscriptable.

Comment: @NathanPierson it's pseudocode. What matters is the algorithm. This is probably from one of those interview prep sites

Comment: @AmandeepSingh my edit might work, but I wrote that without compiling or even using an IDE. The idea is to traverse and whenever we are done with a node mark with -1 and clear all -1's ahead. Give it a try and see what you get with more than 3 subarrays.

Comment: Would your code only work for a certain amount of groups or any amount of groups (sub-arrays length in the `map`)?

Comment: Any amount of groups, although you need to check for edge cases, like having one group, two groups, groups with only one number, etc. I suggest you try it, get it working on the base case, then add more groups, etc.

Comment: What does the variable `indexes` store?

Comment: @AmandeepSingh there you have a working solution that can take any number of groups. Edge cases not tested. I really cannot explain how it works, just stare at it until you get it. All I can say is that it uses modulus to know when to move an index once a subarray has been traversed. Just look at it...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution in recursive way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void solve(vector < vector<int> >map, vector<int>ans, int pos) {
    if(pos == map.size()) {
        for(int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++) {
            cout<<ans[i];
            if(i != ans.size() - 1) {
                cout<<"->";
            }
            else {
                cout<<endl;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < map[pos].size(); i++) {
        ans.push_back(map[pos][i]);
        solve(map, ans, pos+1);
        ans.pop_back();
    }
}

int main() {

    vector<vector<int> > map = {
        { 1, 2 },
        { 3, 4, 5 },
        { 6, 7 }
    };
    
    vector<int>empty;
    
    solve(map, empty, 0);
}
```

Output:

```
1->3->6
1->3->7
1->4->6
1->4->7
1->5->6
1->5->7
2->3->6
2->3->7
2->4->6
2->4->7
2->5->6
2->5->7
```